# not able to find out the file and file path

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services

I have an `.asmx` file which is holding many methods inside the file. When I'm trying to create new class file its happening but I am not able to access the class name into the `.asmx` file.

One more thing, when I am clicking on any class name which is mentioned inside the `.asmx` and pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> it is taking me to some other file which is not editable one.

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

[Careercouncelling.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qARz0.png)

[Student.aspx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pENXL.png)

[DataAccess file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYZpP.png)

[DataAccess[1.0.0.0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Fli.png)

Comment: when i was performing fn+f12 on any one of the class name its taking me to some other file which is metadata file.we cant perform any action with that file.

Comment: can you give screenshot of CareerCounseling.cs ?

Comment: i had given the screenshot what you have asked

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of one of the other affected classes? Have you checked the namespaces are correct and as expected?

Comment: i have two folders in my project one is models and one is entities.in each file i have to create one class file.other classes which are already created i can access which are all classes im creating now im not able to access into .asmx file

Comment: EF has nothing to do with files and file paths. And there's no standard keyboard keystroke that involves the  `Fn` key. Most keyboards don't even have an Fn key. What is that keystroke supposed to do in your machine?

Comment: when i was checking in the references there are two dataAccess im getting which are containing different files.the file DataAccess contains all classes including the classes what i have created but the file DataAccess[1.0.0.0]  is not having the class files which are created by me.i attached the two dataaccess files kindly check and help me out.

Comment: fn+f12 takes me to the file where that method is created.

Comment: Are you referencing a compiled dll in your project? What references do you?

Comment: i have many references in my project main is DataAccess.dll

Comment: which one of DataAccess you use? 
in your asmx, which namespace is it ? (is it "namespace DataAccess" ? -- like CareerCounseling.cs) and do you include "using DataAccess" ?